# Repeat last element in Flux if no elements are available upstream

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am searching for a way to repeat the last element when the subscriber of a `Flux` signals `onNext` but the publisher did not supply a new element.

Of course this approach would logically introduce eager streaming, but in my case that's exactly what I want, similarly to `onBackpressureDrop` and others, where an infinite demand is requested upstream.

I kind of need the exact opposite - with my subscriber being faster than the publisher.

Comment: keep in mind Reactive Streams makes no guarantee as to _when_ an element is emitted by a `Publisher` once it receives `request(1)`, so there's no way for the `Subscriber` to "get a preview" of whether or not the `Publisher` will honor its newly made request, other than receiving an `onComplete` signal. You _could_ conceptually start a countdown after each request and replay the last value to downstream, but then you'd need to properly treat the upstream value if it arrives eg. right after said countdown (queue it, propagate it IF there is demand, etc...), so that's probably a custom operator

Answer (score 1):

I struggle to think of a case where it wouldn't be better for the subscriber to simply cache the last emitted value within itself and do what it needs to do there (whether that's looping, firing on a scheduled executor or something else entirely) rather than deliberately having an infinite demand on the last value emitted by the `Flux`.

Something akin to the following *might* work, but is incredibly hacky (that being said, I couldn't think of a better way):

```
flux.subscribe(str -> {
    Mono.just(str).repeat().takeUntilOther(flux.next())
            .subscribe(s -> {
                //Actual subscriber
            });
});
```

Comment: I understand your concern as to why. To explain why, it's merly a question of preference - I would always go for the more functional approach, which this is.

Comment: I think a comment was deleted here. Did that refer to the use of `subscribe`?